ImportError: cannot import name 'get_nearest_node' from 'osmnx.distance'
I am trying to get MaaSSim running, but I get stuck right at the beginning following the instructions. I can download the git repository, I downloaded osmnx (and it works), but then I get stuck. Would someone be able to help me in this matter?
    import MaaSSim.utils
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\src\maassim\MaaSSim\utils.py", line 14, in <module>
        from osmnx.distance import get_nearest_node
    ImportError: cannot import name 'get_nearest_node' from 'osmnx.distance' (C:    \Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osmnx\distance.py). Did you mean: 'nearest_nodes'?
    import logging
    from dotmap import DotMap
    import MaaSSim.simulators
    from MaaSSim.data_structures import structures as inData
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\src\maassim\MaaSSim\simulators.py", line 8, in <module>
        from MaaSSim.maassim import Simulator
      File "C:\Users\user\src\maassim\MaaSSim\maassim.py", line 24, in <module>
        from MaaSSim.utils import initialize_df
      File "C:\Users\user\src\maassim\MaaSSim\utils.py", line 14, in <module>
        from osmnx.distance import get_nearest_node
    ImportError: cannot import name 'get_nearest_node' from 'osmnx.distance' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osmnx\distance.py). Did you mean: 'nearest_nodes'?


As noted here, get_nearest_node was removed from OSMnx in version 1.1.0.
From the error message, you can tell that MasSSim.utils is trying to import this function:
from osmnx.distance import get_nearest_node

I.e., the package is dependent on an earlier version of OSMnx, and your version is doubtlessly >= 1.1.0.
Which version would be the correct one to use? Oddly enough, OSMnx has vanished from requirements.txt, even though it is still (generically) listed under dependencies in "README.md". But it used to be included, until it was deleted on 2020-09-23. See L10 from Update requirements.txt:
- osmnx==0.15.1

I.e., one assumes that installation should work with version 0.15.1, following the installation instructions, adding the specific version at the end:
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx==0.15.1

If that does not fix the issue, you might want to reach out to the author of the package, whose contact details you can trace both on GitHub and here.
